# Force RelativeLayout focus for onTouchEvent

Tags: android, touch, android-relativelayout

I am on development of my first game. The mechanics is simple: pop bubbles that move randomly on screen. My canvas is a RelativeLayout over Activity. The layout is simple.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header" />
```

The touch event is defined by implementing `onTouch` method from `View.OnTouchListener`. A class extract follows:

```
public class BubbleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private RelativeLayout mFrame;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        //...
    }       
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //...
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bubble);
        mFrame = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        //...
    }       
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mFrame.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes touch event doesn't occurs. I am wondering if there is some kind of mechanism for grab the focus always, ensuring the touch event in my RelativeLayout object.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch all `TouchEvent`s by you `RelativeLayout` then implement custom View extends `RelativeLayout` and handle events in `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.

Example:

```
public class RelativeLayoutExt extends RelativeLayout {
    public RelativeLayoutExt(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RelativeLayoutExt(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RelativeLayoutExt(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public RelativeLayoutExt(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // TODO handle your touches here
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```